# CSS3 - Variable height accordion using transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've coded two small jQuery based scripts, one of accordions, and one of tabs, but then i realized that they were the same : get the clicked tab's index among other tabs, and only show the content that has the same index among contents.

But there's one annoying difference between the two : the animation. While tabs are only using the display property, accordions need to animate the height of content blocks.

Problem is that it is not possible to animate from height: 0; to height: auto;. There is a way to do it differently, using max-height, as described in [this] other SO question, but i don't really like this solution because it's hard-coded and doesn't always work.

Is there a way to animate a block's height from 0 to it's content height **without using max-height or javascript** ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What's wrong with `max-height`? Works for me everytime

Comment: Well you have to provide a maximum size. If you put it too big, the animation will be very fast, but if you put it too small, some long contents will be partially hidden. And i'd like to code something that doesn't have to care of content size.

Comment: @DevishOne Please read the question before posting useless links...

Answer (score 0):

No. CSS transitions can only go from a value (or no value indicating a zero value) to another value. They cannot go from a value (or zero value) to a non-zero undetermined value.

Comment: I'm telling you that, under your conditions (no JS and no max-height) there is NO workaround. That is the only answer.